# Cordova doesn't track gps state if it's on/off

Tags: android, ios, cordova, gps

I'm using the `navigator.geolocation` objet to watch the position of the gps. I've found a bug, here are the steps:

1) Gps if off.
2) App start.
3) Gps is activated from the notification panel.
4) App doesn't notice any change.

At this point, only a `window.location.reload()` makes the app recognize that the gps is active.

If the App is started with the gps on, switching it on and off while the app is running cause no issue, the app recognize its state.

Do you know any way to solve this problem?

Comment: And worse even sometimes neither success nor error callbacks are called when GPS is switch on/off or form on to off. Yes this is a mess. An approach could be to request location and checking error-messages otherwise use settimeout to proceed your code. But it depends on your option-params as well. timeout should be high enough to give your device a change to get current location otherwise it could fail at bad positions.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you

https://github.com/mablack/cordova-diagnostic-plugin

I think the Geolocation API does not give you an error if the GPS is on/off, just a timeout error if it is not able to get a lock in the time limit you specify, but I tested it a while ago and I might be mistaking.